# ART stackexchange section

Tags: feature-request

How can I open a new Stack exchange section to talk about art. In general.

About questioning, history, philosophy, infringement with technology.

Answer (score 5):

There is a process to creating new Stack Exchange sites.

1. Propose a site on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
2. Define the scope
3. Get supporters
4. With enough supporters, you will get a private beta
5. With a successful private beta, it will progress to a public beta

There is currently a whole [Arts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/1/arts) section.

What you are describing, however, is overly vague. And our sites don't lend themselves to **discussions**. They are for Questions and Answers.